# Creating content input form with custom theme (Drupal)

Tags: drupal, drupal-hooks

I'm creating a site which I want to place content input form in custom themed template. I opted to do this because I wanted the whole site to be looked uniform. That said, I'm not sure as to what is the best approach to do this. Is it proper to invoke hook_insert/delete/update and hook_perm/hook_access by myself or is there anyway I can still use my custom theme and write a code in a way that drupal would take care of invoking appropriate hooks accordingly?
Thanks in advance

PS : I'm on drupal 6.x

Answer (score 0):

You can make your website uniform by just changing the looks of the site by just changing in the theme's page.tpl.php. and  by changing css and remove all the drupal links.
But if you want to change the default modules like user registration or admin part. Then you can do it but it will require very good knowledge of php and most hard part, you have to study very well of drupal's apis.  like fapi.[called as forms api ] 
But if you want many changes in your site then I much prefer make your website without any cms. 
Bcz it will give you freedom to do anything in anyway.

i have made website in drupal but i have created my own theme. 
But for my site, it was not very big site. so i have created by my own page.tpl.php.

---

Nitz.